# How can I get stored value in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to get the value of my stored user from my store

but when I tried on onMounted function

```
onMounted(async () => {
       console.log('user', store.state.user)  //here i can see the values
        const info = computed(() => {
        return store.state.user
      })
      console.log('info', info)
```

it does not give the information, I am getting `info.name` undefined

what happening here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`info` is a ref, it cannot have `info.name`. It's a mistake to use `computed` inside `mounted` hook, it should be directly inside `setup`:

```
const info = computed(() => store.state.user)

onMounted(async () => {
      console.log('info', info.value)
});
```

`store.state.user` value is not guaranteed to be up-to-date at the time when it's accessed. In case it changes during the component's lifespan, it needs to be accessed inside a watcher or another computed property.

Comment: i think i need to use an observer, because your answer does not worked

Comment: It should be no different than using store.state.user directly. In case store.state.user.name is not available at this moment then yes, you need to watch the value or postpone the component where it's used.

Comment: please i want to postpone the component

Comment: See https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/suspense.html#introduction

Comment: help me with  watch the value please

Comment: It's `watchEffect(() => { console.log('info', info.value) })`